# Organic Groups (7.23) and D7 | drush or cmdline integration?

Tags: drush, organic-groups

Just wondering how to manage OG in D7 from command line oder drush. OG seems frequently used so I'm surprised not to see any method to manage OG from shell, e.g. like create, modify Ogroups... As far as I know there were some former OG-DRUSH integrations in D6 but not in D7. Someone pointed out that the 'feature' module might be a solution (as part of the installation?). Anybody there who's willing to share his knowledge or give some information?

Comment: There is lots of discussion about Drush in the Organic Groups issue queue. Do you have a specific question or problem?

Comment: Thanks for answer. There are no OG problems in general. I just would like to do a drush drupal installation and create OG and its (already drush created) users on the fly. Before starting to use OG, I just created 'roles' as a replacement for missing (ACL) groups within drupal. Then I divided users into different 'groups' = roles but in the long run this turns out to become too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started, but never had time to finish Drush commands for og-6.x-1.x.  Please see https://drupal.org/node/1090438 for the preliminary implementation.  I don't know why no one else has picked this up; I agree it would be useful.

For og-7.x-2.x, I do some programmatic operations in my sandbox project https://drupal.org/sandbox/greg1anderson/2049677.  These are not broken out into direct og operations, but it might serve as a starting point for someone who wanted to pick up the task of adding Drush commands to organic groups.

Finally, for anyone who wants to quickly make a Drush command from a template, see https://drupal.org/project/drushify.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Your feature was just that one what I saw in D6 as I realized that there was no further development in D7. I have to agree, that I don't understand why no one continue this excellent (drush related) work, too. Unfortunately, I'm not a drupal developer just more a drupal user who struggles with drupal's multiple ACL related modules.

Comment: Your sandbox project of course sounds very interesting to bigger sites or communities. From users' perspective it might make user/group management more flexible. From admin's point of view I'd prefer drush integration after all. I still wonder whether drush/og module owners cooperate for a seamless integration or not.

Comment: I just posted a D7 patch which implements a couple of Drush commands.  See the above issue in the queue for details.  And I started with Drushify! :)